# Ionic image slider not loading on iOS

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, mobile, ionic3

I have an ionic app containing an image slider which uses the ion-slides component to provide slides between images retrieved from url's.

My problem is that the images display correctly on Android, but on iOS the images do not display, only when rotating the device to landscape do the images appear and then also work in portrait mode.

Any advice on how to make the images appear correctly on iOS?

Below is my code sample:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-slides pager
  #imageSlider>
    <ion-slide *ngFor='let url of imageUrls'>
      <ion-img [src]='url'></ion-img>
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

In the typescript file, imageUrls is an array of type string, containing URL's for the images to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

1. Changed `<ion-img>` to just a normal `img`
2. In typescript file, added the following to `ionViewCanEnter`:

   ```
   @ViewChild('imageSlider') slider: Slides;

   ...

   ionViewCanEnter() {
      this.slider.centeredSlides = true;
   }
   ```

The images now load on iOS.

Template sample:

```
<ion-content padding>
   <ion-slides pager
   #imageSlider>
   <ion-slide *ngFor='let url of imageUrls'>
      <img [src]='url'>
   </ion-slide>
   </ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```